# Trim White Space in All Input Text Fields in Application on Blur/Exit

Tags: jquery

**SOLUTION (TRIM LEADING/TRAILING ON BLUR)**

```
$('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
});
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I need to trim all whitespace in all input text fields globally. Options 1 and 2 don't work, while Option 3 does work. Why is that?

```
        // Attach an on-blur event to trim whitespace on all input fields
        $('input[type=text]').blur(function() {
            alert('Blur Before Val = ' + $(this).val() + ' Length = ' + $(this).val().length);
            $.trim($(this).val());  // OPTION 1 DOES NOT WORK
            $(this).val().trim();   // OPTION 2 DOES NOT WORK
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));  // OPTION 3 WORKS
            alert('Blur After Val = ' + $(this).val() + ' Length = ' + $(this).val().length);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.trim($(this).val());  // OPTION 1 DOES NOT WORK
```

This one doesn't update the textbox. Also, it removes only those whitespaces that appear at the beginning or at the end of the string. See [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

```
$(this).val().trim();   // OPTION 2 DOES NOT WORK
```

Again, this one doesn't update the textbox. You can update the textbox's value like `$(this).val(newValue)`. Also, it only removes the whitespaces from the beginning and the end. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));  // OPTION 3 WORKS
```

This is correct syntax to update the textbox's value. The regex (`/\s/g`) matches to every whitespace - including those between words, and replaces them with empty string. So, that's why it works.

Comment: and how would I remove the Leading/Trailing whitespace only in the RegExp (#3)?

Comment: You don't need regex for that. Plain JS `trim` function is adequate. Try this: `$(this).val($(this).val().trim());`